# Set asp.net page to one time only showing

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

How do I set a asp.net page to show only once? So if a user logs back in again that page wont be displayed again.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? No Post Backs, Only once per session?

Comment: What do you mean by "only once"  You mean per user, per day, ever?  Do you have a database?

Comment: only once the first time they log in and never again hence only once

Comment: Is it a static page like `mypage.aspx` or a dynamic page `mypage.aspx?showOnceId=123`?  Also, can multiple users view the same page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a flag for the user in the DB and display based on that.

Comment: Agree, to expand a bit - have a column that defaults to null or 0 for each user; when the user has read (and if necessary, accepted) the content, set the flag to 1.  Then only display the page if the flag is not 1..

Comment: yup this is the method im looking for, will get some code up soon see if i get it right

Answer (score 0):

You'd have store a flag in your database or elsewhere that indicated that a user has already seen that page.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a record in your backend database for each user, you could add a bit field e.g. `IsPageViewed`. In the `Page_Load()` event of the 1-time-only page, set the value to 1.

When the user next logs in you can then redirect according to this flag.